# Show unnumbered sections anywhere in Beamer TOC

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning, starred-version, unnumbered-sections

Section 10.5 of the [LaTeX Beamer manual](https://mirror.lyrahosting.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) specifies the different options for generating a table of contents. One of them is:

> `firstsection=⟨section number⟩` specifies which section should be numbered as section “1.” This is
> useful if you have a first section (like an overview section) that should not receive a number. Section
> numbers are not shown by default. To show them, you must install a different table of contents
> templates.

There is a similar option `lastsection`. In my case, however, I need **an unnumbered section in the middle** of my sections, not the start or the end. The following is a photoshopped mock-up (a *toc*k-up, if you will) of what I mean:

[image: Tockup]

It's acceptable if you redefine `\section*` in your answer, as I want all `\section`s and `\section*`s to be shown in the TOC and `\section*`'s only default purpose is precisely not to be shown in TOC. Hence, the above mock-up could result from the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usebeamercolor{dolphin}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    
    \section*{Intro}
    \section{First section}
    \section{Second section}
    \section*{Nope}
    \section{Third section}
    \section*{Outro}
    
    \begin{frame}   
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code introduces a command `\nonumsec` that creates a `\section*` and adds an entry to the `.toc` file with the final argument set to 0. This causes Beamer (somehow) to not print the number. The code for adding an entry is copied from the Beamer source, particularly `beamerbasesection.sty`.

There may be side effects so test carefully.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usebeamercolor{dolphin}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nonumsec}[1]{%
\section*{#1}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@sectionintoc{\the\c@section}{#1}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}%
        {0}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    
    \nonumsec{Intro}
    \section{First section}
    \section{Second section}
    \nonumsec{Nope}
    \section{Third section}
    \nonumsec{Outro}
    
    \begin{frame}   
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Resulting TOC file:

```
\beamer@sectionintoc {1}{Intro}{2}{0}{0}
\beamer@sectionintoc {2}{First section}{2}{0}{1}
\beamer@sectionintoc {3}{Second section}{2}{0}{2}
\beamer@sectionintoc {4}{Nope}{2}{0}{0}
\beamer@sectionintoc {5}{Third section}{2}{0}{3}
\beamer@sectionintoc {6}{Outro}{2}{0}{0}
```

PDF output is the same as in the *toc*k-up.